# How to completely remove the influence of a variable y from a variable x

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, multivariate-analysis

Consider the case where you want to predict a certain objective variable z using an independent variable x.

At this time, another independent variable y contains both information about z and information about x as well.

If I don't want machine learning model to use information of y in when to predict z, how can I get rid of information of y from x?
If there is only a linear relationship between x and y, I think that it can be removed by setting the correlation to 0, but is there a method that can be used when the type of relationship is unknown?

Comment: Is something inadequate about omitting $Y$ from your input to the model?

Comment: I assume that there exist two probabilistic representations, one for $z$ conditional on $x$ and $y$, and one for $x$ conditional on $y$. A way to remove the information of $y$, I believe is to integrate $y$ from both the probabilistic representations.